# How to make two axios requests and save both responses in a hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using `Axios` to make API calls to my backend. The problem is that I want to make a call, save the response in a hook, than make another call and save the response in the same hook. I must make the second call after receiving the response from the first one, since in my backend the second call listen to an EventEmmiter:

```
const [invoice, setInvoice] = useState({
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    content: null,
    paid: false
  });

function createInvoice() {
    setInvoice({ ...invoice, loading: true });
    api
      .post("/lightning/createinvoice", {
        amount: values.amount
      })
      .then(response => {
        setInvoice({
          loading: false,
          error: false,
          content: response.data,
          paid: false
        });
        return api.get("/lightning/invoicestatus", {
          params: { id: response.data.id }
        });
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.status === "Confirmed")
          setInvoice({ ...invoice, paid: true });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setInvoice({ loading: false, error: true, content: null });
      });
  }
```

This code works, however I get `invoices.content: null`. I suspect that `setInvoice({ ...invoice, paid: true });` fails, as the `invoice` state doesn't have its most updated state.

How should I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at [react-loads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loads)

Comment: Based on your code, the only time `content` will be null is when your request catches an error. Did you make sure that you get to the second `.then` call where you check for the `status === 'confirmed' ?`

Comment: Hi @AfikDeri. Yes I'm sure, my backend is receiving the second call, and `invoice.paid` is being set to `true`

Comment: If you check your `content` before the second api call, do you see the data being set properly in your state?

Comment: Where are you actually checking it is `null`? What is in first `response.data`? Knowing the back end is receiving is only part of how you need to debug this. Can find out a  lot by using browser dev tools. Inspect the actual requests in the network tab for example

Comment: @AfikDeri, yes between the first and second call, `content` receives `response.data`. After the second call `content` receives `null`, when `setInvoice({ ...invoice, paid: true });` is triggered.
@charlietfl I'm not, but I need to keep the `response.data` in `content` after the first API call. I use React Dev Tools and I can see the state changing, so I know the problem is not from receiving the data from the backend

Comment: I'm not sure, but it probably has something to do with the closure of each `then` function. try to create a `let content = invoice.content` at the top of your function and on each `.then()` call set it again like so: `setInvoice({...invoice, content: content, paid: true\false})`. It might work.

Comment: @AfikDeri that's a good idea. I'm gonna implement this way, but I guess there is a fancier way to solve it using hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a cleaner, much readable approach rather than just promise callbacks. Let me know if you find any issue, as I am not sure about your actual API calls which I can test. But the code below should work irrespectively.

```
  const [invoice, setInvoice] = useState({
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    content: null,
    paid: false
  });

  const createInvoice = async (api, values) => {
    try {
      setInvoice({ ...invoice, loading: true });
      const firstResponse = await api.post("/lightning/createinvoice", {
        amount: values.amount
      });
      setInvoice({
        ...invoice,
        content: firstResponse.data
      });

      const secondResponse = await api.get("/lightning/invoicestatus", {
        params: { id: firstResponse.data.id }
      });

      if (secondResponse.data.status === "Confirmed") {
        setInvoice({ ...invoice, paid: true });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setInvoice({ loading: false, error: true, content: null });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Much better than my approach. I'm gonna refactor it. Thanks!